# Getting ALL mouse event types

Tags: gwt, mouseevent

If i set a handler for a mouse over event, it would look something like this.

```
boxPanel.addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent e) {
               //do something
            }
        }, MouseOverEvent.getType());
```

Notice the `MouseOverEvent.getType()` at the end, as it pertains to my question.

If i want to add a handler for ALL mouse events, like so

```
spotlightPanel.addDomHandler(new HandlesAllMouseEvents() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
            //do something
        }
        @Override
        public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
            //do something
        }
        @Override
        public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
            //do something
        }
        @Override
        public void onMouseUp(MouseUpEvent event) {
            //do something
        }
        @Override
        public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) { 
            //do something
        }
        @Override
        public void onMouseWheel(MouseWheelEvent event) {
            //do something
        }
    }, ???);
```

What would the ??? be? I tried things like `MouseEvent.getType()` but the method didn't exist. I tried inputting multiple events like `(MouseOverEvent.getType(), MouseOutEvent.getType())` but the syntax is all wrong. What's the proper way to reference all mouse events for the `HandlesAllMouseEvents()`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `HandlesAllMouseEvents` is an interface for multiple event types, you have to add each event type to your widget but reusing the same handler.

```
    Widget spotlightPanel = [...]

    HandlesAllMouseEvents mouseHandler = new HandlesAllMouseEvents(){
        public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {}
        public void onMouseUp(MouseUpEvent event) {}
        public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {}
        public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {}
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {}
        public void onMouseWheel(MouseWheelEvent event) {}
    };

    spotlightPanel.addDomHandler(mouseHandler, MouseDownEvent.getType());
    spotlightPanel.addDomHandler(mouseHandler, MouseUpEvent.getType());
    spotlightPanel.addDomHandler(mouseHandler, MouseMoveEvent.getType());
    spotlightPanel.addDomHandler(mouseHandler, MouseOverEvent.getType());
    spotlightPanel.addDomHandler(mouseHandler, MouseWheelEvent.getType());
```